# Matlab: How can I manipulate a Fourier transform in Fourier space?

Tags: matlab, fft

Given a function f(t) in the time domain t. Its Fourier transform is F(w) in the frequency domain.
How can I change the Fourier transform in Fourier space w, e.g. how can I compute F(w)*w?

I have already done the Fourier transform on a signal x with FFT(x) but then how do I proceed to multiply the FFT(x) with w? I really don't know what to do here...

Comment: Did you try `.*` (multiplication)?

Comment: I dont think that is the question. I think he doesnt know how to get `w` to begin with...

Comment: @bla That makes more sense but was not clear at all?

Comment: Sorry, yes I did not know how to get w at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you dont know how to get `w`.
Assuming your signal is `x(t)` over a uniform grid `t`:

```
N  = numel(x);
dt = t(2)-t(1);
df = 1/(N*dt);      % the frequency resolution (df=1/max_T)

if mod(N,2)==0
    f_vector = df*((1:N)-1-N/2);    
else
    f_vector = df*((1:N)-0.5-N/2);   
end

w=f_vector;
answer = fftshift(fft(x)).*w;
```

There's a chance you need to multiply `w` with `2*pi` or `pi`, I wasn't too careful so check and see what makse sense

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked!